# Accessing google-ckoud-storage form a non app engine application on local machine-

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage

I need help with accessing google cloud store from a non app engine java application when running on a local machine, planing to run it on a vm in the future. Im currently rather lost and would like to have some kind of example of how I should do this (I have googled it but havent found anything that works).

I have been playing around with the following, but dont really know what how to inti httpRequestInitializer. So havent been able to even compile it.

Credential cred  = DatastoreHelper.getServiceAccountCredential(account, privateKeyFile);
DatastoreOptions options = new DatastoreOptions("dataset","something",httpRequestInitializer,cred);

All help is very much appreciated or direction to some example..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a good example of accessing Google Cloud Storage using the Google API Client Library for Java available here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/json-api-java-samples

Here's the basic code to set up a Credential using a service account:

```
String emailAddress = "YOUR-SERVICE-ACCOUNT-NAME@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
    .setTransport(httpTransport)
    .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
    .setServiceAccountId(emailAddress)
    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("MyProject.p12"))
    .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton(StorageScopes.DEVSTORAGE_FULL_CONTROL))
    .build();
```

Comment: Thx, that helps, any clue how I can use this in creating a Datastore object, It would be excellent if that was pointing to the one I have in the cloud.

Comment: If you plan to run it on a VM, the easiest way is to use DatastoreHelper.getOptionsfromEnv(). However, using it from outside a VM means you'll need to set a few environment variables. There is example code here: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/getstarted/start_java/

Comment: HI,when using Datastore datastore = DatastoreFactory.get().create(DatastoreHelper.getOptionsfromEnv().credential(credential).build()); In combination with your code above im getting an exception "datastore dataset not set in options" and with 

DatastoreFactory.get().create(DatastoreHelper.getOptionsfromEnv().dataset("xxxx") un getting exception that im not using any credentials, even if i set env variables.

any clue?

Comment: Sounds like the environment variables are not getting through to your app. Maybe create a new question?